# Trouble making a correct sum

Tags: javascript, standards, standard-deviation

I'm calculating standard deviation for a graph and although I'm getting the correct values for the square of each point on the graph, I'm having trouble getting the sum of the squared values. I should get 17.20 but am getting 14 instead. It only seems to be adding the first number and not the decimal places. Here is my code:

```
var1 = (var1 * var1).toFixed(2); //alert(var1); getting 2.56
var2 = (var2 * var2).toFixed(2); //alert(var2); getting 1.96
var3 = (var3 * var3).toFixed(2); //alert(var3); getting 5.76
var4 = (var4 * var4).toFixed(2); //alert(var4); getting 6.76
var5 = (var5 * var5).toFixed(2); //alert(var5); getting 0.16

var sum = (  parseInt(var1)+parseInt(var2)+parseInt(var3)+parseInt(var4)+parseInt(var5) ).toFixed(2);

alert(sum); // should get 17.20, but getting 14
```

Comment: Why do you change things to with`. toFixed(2)` to a stringified float, and then parse it back to an int, losing the floating part? Have you tried parseFloat() ?

Comment: What do you think the "Int" part of `parseInt` means?

Comment: you get `2+1+5+6 = 14` use `parseFloat()` instead

Comment: Thanks. I know i'm a dummy. Not a "real" programmer. I'll try parseFloat().

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for you to be using `parseInt` here unless you only want to sum the integer parts of the squares.

[parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) "parses a string and returns an integer." If you change the `parseInt` calls for each square to `parseFloat`, it will correctly parse the floating point values from your strings and sum them properly.

Comment: change it to parseFloat, since he changed the multiplied floats into a string with toFixed(2)

Comment: Right, I missed that part first time I read through it. I was about to edit my answer when SO went down for maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `parseInt` since it converts your Float-values into Integers, which means each product is being flattened:

`2 + 1 + 5 + 6 + 0 = 14`

To achieve the right result you could also write:

```
var1 = Math.pow(var1, 2);
var2 = Math.pow(var2, 2);
var3 = Math.pow(var3, 2);
var4 = Math.pow(var4, 2);
var5 = Math.pow(var5, 2);

var sum = var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5;

alert(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Or to write less lines:

```
var fixedSum = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5].reduce(function(acc, curr){
  return acc + Math.pow(curr, 2)
}, 0).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the integer sum and not the decimals because you `parseInt` the strings. Just use `parseFloat` instead and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are parsing each variable to an integer, cutting off the decimal places

Integers are whole numbers so your real operation is this:

```
var1 2.56->2  + var2:1.96->1 ...
parseInt(var1)+parseInt(var2)+parseInt(var3)+parseInt(var4)+parseInt(var5) ).toFixed(2);
```

you'll want to remove the ParseInt and just sum them together as such:

```
sum = (var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 +var5).toFixed(2);
```

I would also suggest you round (use toFixed) only once, as continually rounding decreases accuracy and in Javascript, it makes the numbers into strings which would cause unexpected results.